# Get row_number of a specificatet column MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Database: MySQL
columns: city, create2 (Timestamp)

I have this query:

```
SELECT city ,COUNT(city) 
FROM content 
WHERE create2 > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)   '
GROUP BY city 
ORDER BY COUNT(city) DESC
```

Now i want to get the ranked position from a city, but i didn't found a solution. Like this:

```
SELECT city ,COUNT(city)    
FROM content 
WHERE create2 > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)   
GROUP BY city 
ORDER BY COUNT(city) DESC 
WHERE city= Berlin
```

Comment: In php get it by from index of returned array

Comment: Where are you calculating ranks? MySQL doesn't have `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Put the query that calculates the rank in a subquery, then select the city you want in the main query.

Comment: This is a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL. Look at the highest-voted answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: with the SubQuery I do not get that, I've already tried all day.

Comment: Which query would you advise me to get to my goal?